# Severe Flex issues

Tags: apache-flex, flex3, flex-builder-3

I seem to be having difficulties getting the trace function to output anything to the console in either Eclipse with the Flex Plug-in, Flex Builder, or even FlexBeans (the Netbeans plug-in for Flex).  I have removed and then reinstalled the Flash player 10 debugger version for both Firefox and IE, rebooting after uninstalling them and then after re-installing them.  I have removed all old versions of Java and updated to the most recent version.

mm.cfg is configured correctly to allow the trace actions to appear in flashlog.txt

I tried removing the Flex Plug-in for eclipse to re-install, and now that I re-installed, I cannot create new Flex projects.  I would rather not uninstall Flex Builder for fear that it will also behave strangely.

ANY ideas would be useful.  Ideally, I need the plug-in to work, but any way I could get tracing to output to the console (in ANY IDE) would be better than what I have now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is actually a combination of issues.  The minor issue was that one application was interfering with Flex Builder Plug-in.  The major issue had to do with a setting which had gotten changed on the Flash debugger.

If you right-click the running SWF and then click Debugger, you can (essencially) tell the VM where to listen for trace actions.  This had been set to another machine on the network, and not my local machine.  As soon as that was switched, everything restored itself.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean by "Flash debugger for both Firefox and IE"; are you referring the debugger versions of the Flash Player available here?

http://www.adobe.com/support/flashplayer/downloads.html

If not, you definitely need those installed in order to be able to write trace() output to the IDE console.

Comment: Flash debugger 10, which can be installed for Firefox as a plug-in, or for IE, through ActiveX.  They have been uninstalled and re-installed multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

I'm almost positive that this is not the issue, but it has confused me on a couple of occasions.

The Debug Application (as opposed to Run Application) keyboard command is different on Mac and PC.  I use both and have gotten them mixed up, which results in my Running when I think I am Debugging, which of course leads to know trace outputs in the console.

Most likely not it, but doesn't hurt to mention it (I hope) :)

-- Evan

Comment: What really bothers me is that the Flash and Flex Builder keyboard commands are completely different.  When I have to switch to Flash, I end up hiding my timeline instead of running a debug session.

Anyway, I found the real issue.

Answer (score 0):

How are you testing the debugger? Have you tried going somewhere like with lots of ads that generally still have their traces in? Or are you just testing it with your own swfs? Have you installed the projector debug version? How is eclipse / flex configured to launch test swfs? Is it in the browser, or in the stand alone player? Do you have any weird mxmlc settings?

I assume you've followed all these instructions?
http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/193/tn_19323.html